# Using OLE in Perl to traverse Outlook folders

Tags: perl, outlook, ole

I've got a script which will happily export messages from a folder in outlook to rfc822 files, fine.

But I want to traverse/iterate/recurse through the entire list of folders in outlook to extract copies of everything.

I'm thwarted by days of unsuccessful web searches.

Point me to TFM that I may R it.

Answer (score 0):

[Mail::Outlook](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail%3a%3aOutlook) 
and [all_folders()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail%3a%3aOutlook#all_folders) method ?